# Множественный тип в столбце

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Вот к примеру есть табличка:

```
CREATE TABLE "Prixod" (
    "ID" serial NOT NULL,
    "Сomposition" ComprositionPrixod[] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Prixod_pk PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
);
```

и есть два типа:

```
Create type ComprositionPrixod AS (
    Name character varying,
    Count numeric,
    Price numeric
);

Create type ComprositiontTransfer AS (
    Name character varying,
    Count numeric
);
```

Можно мне как нибудь сделать, что бы в столбец могли записаться оба типа:
Что то вроде: `"Сomposition" ComprositionPrixod[] or ComprositiontTransfer[]  NOT NULL`?

Answer (score 1):

Существует возможность наследования типов как в ООП. 
Например, ваш тип CompositionPrixod может быть унаследован от CompositionTransfer (думаю, вы понимаете, почему).
Но такая возможность есть далеко не во всех диалектах SQL и СУБД. В постгресе, например, такой возможности нет. Есть другие, менее изящные способы. Например, композиция, inner join и ещё куча всяких костылей. В вашем случае, я бы посоветовал использовать наследование ТАБЛИЦ, а не типов и в вашей таблице указывать внешний ключ. Пример:

```
create table Parent (
  column1 integer,
  column2 varchar(80)
);

create table Child (
  column3 date,
) inherits(Parent);
```

Если нужны именно типы, вот тут товарищ отвечает в избытке на данный вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28294739/derived-type-in-postgresql